# How mock new object in method - phpunit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm testing php code with phpunit and I have a problem:

I'm testing class:

```
class ClassName
{
  public function MethodName()
  {
    // something

    $objectName = new Object();
    $variableName = $objectName->execute();

    // something
  }
}
```

I want create mock of Object. I do not want call real method execute(). I dont know how do this with phpunit.
I know dependency injection, but IMHO this case is not solved with dependency injection.

Thanks you for answers. I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, this case could be solved with depency injection. Lets say you are not instantiating Object inside MethodName, but injecting it. Whether through contructor, setter, or method does not matter that much for the principle.

```
class ClassName
{
    public function MethodName(Object $objectName)
    {
        // something

        $variableName = $objectName->execute();

        // something
    }
}
```

Because you now dont instaniate the object inside the method you want to test, you can pass it a mock when you want to test it.

```
public function testMethodName(){
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Object')->getMock();

    $className = new ClassName;

    $result = $className->MethodName($mock);

    $this->assertTrue($result);
}
```

I did not run this testmethod, but I think it illustrates the point of depency injection for testability.

Comment: I am no expert myself. I do think that writing tests also makes the code itself cleaner, because you think better about its structure. http://youtu.be/RlfLCWKxHJ0 and http://youtu.be/-FRm3VPhseI are good general talks, and http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/dependency-injection-with-php-53 for a depency injection argument from the creator of Pimple and other great projects...

Comment: I think this strategy is not always appropriate. Like what if the object that needs to be created in a method under test is something like \DateTime(). Or an event object that gets passed to an event dispatcher.

Comment: It really does depend on the situation. Patterns and best practices are not laws or applicable 100% of the time. They do usually give good handles on how to solve problems in a elegant way. That being said, sometimes it still makes sense to use dependency injection. But instead of the object instance itself, you'd inject a builder or factory.